Unable to find correct bash syntax for comparing numbers
Part of a long script I'm simply trying to compare two numbers, one is constant and the other one is retrieved via ffprobe (The 474 in the error messages is the height found by ffprobe)
CURRENT_RES=$(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 "${fn}")
  if [[ $CURRENT_RES -gt 1080 ]]; then
    echo "leaving preset normal"
    SLOW_PRESET=("" "")
  else
    echo "setting preset to slow"
    SLOW_PRESET=(-preset slow)
  fi;

produces:
/usr/local/bin/startScreen.sh: line 95: [[: 474

474: syntax error in expression (error token is "474")
setting preset to slow

I also tried arithmetic operators like:
  if (($CURRENT_RES>1080)); then
    echo "leaving preset normal"
    SLOW_PRESET=("" "")
  else
    echo "setting preset to slow"
    SLOW_PRESET=(-preset slow)
  fi;

got a slightly different, but essentially same error message like:
/usr/local/bin/startScreen.sh: line 95: ((: 474

474>1080: syntax error in expression (error token is "474>1080")
setting preset to slow

What's even more baffling is there 15 lines below this block there is another comparison which works perfectly fine!
if [[ $CURRENT_RES -gt $CONVERT_HEIGHT ]]; then

I thought may be the inline written 1080 number is confusing the if expression so I tried assigning 1080 to variable and reusing it, which changed nothing.
edit: (dropping this here in case someone else falls into same mistake)
following up on Shawn's advice from comments using cat -v showed 474 was repeated twice.
For debugging purposes ran:
ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of json "filename.mp4"

to find this weird format:
{
    "programs": [
        {
            "streams": [
                {
                    "height": 472
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "height": 472
        }
    ]
}

finally changed the ffprobe command to:
CURRENT_RES=$(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of json "${fn}" | jq .streams[0].height)

to resolve the issue.

Does cat -v <<<"$CURRENT_RES" show any unusual characters?

You could try printf '%q\n' "$CURRENT_RES" ,  just to see the value of the variable, quoted.

@Shawn 474 was printed twice! for some reason simple echo $CURRENT_RES did not show this. To debug it, I used json output for ffprobe instead of csv, and there were two different blocks, linking to same stream. changing the ffprobe command to CURRENT_RES=$(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of json "${fn}" | jq .streams[0].height) fixed the issue.
Thanks!

@kali echo $var can be remarkably misleading, for a number of reasons. See "I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else".

The output of the ffprobe command is not a single number.
I can reproduce the error message:
CURRENT_RES="474

474"
[[ $CURRENT_RES -gt 1080 ]]

outputs
bash: [[: 474

474: syntax error in expression (error token is "474")


Try modifying your script like this:
CURRENT_RES=$(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 "${fn}" | tr -d '[:space:]')

if [[ "$CURRENT_RES" -gt 1080 ]]; then   echo "leaving preset normal"  SLOW_PRESET=("" "") else   echo "setting preset to slow"   SLOW_PRESET=(-preset slow) fi

tr -d '[:space:]' removes any spaces or newline characters from the output of ffprobe. Now CURRENT_RES should be clean for comparison, resolving the syntax errors you encountered.

Using jq to process ffprobe output is actually very clever.
Here I show how to extract multiple values with a single call to ffprobe:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\t' read -r width height < <(
  ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream -of json "filename.mp4" |
    jq -r '.streams[0]|[.width, .height]|join("\t")'
)


Any time I start seeing this sort of confusing message, the first thing I do is insert a set -x above the line it's complaining about. Being able to see what the parser is working with can really help.
$: x=$'2\n3'
$: set -x
$: if (( x > 2 )); then echo up; else echo down; fi # don't need $ in (())
+ ((  x > 2  ))
bash: ((: 2
3: syntax error in expression (error token is "3")
+ echo down
down
$: if (( $x > 2 )); then echo up; else echo down; fi # if you use it
+ ((  2
3 > 2  ))
bash: ((: 2
3 > 2 : syntax error in expression (error token is "3 > 2 ")
+ echo down
down
$: if [[ "$x" -gt 2 ]]; then echo up; else echo down; fi
+ [[ 2
3 -gt 2 ]]
bash: [[: 2
3: syntax error in expression (error token is "3")
+ echo down
down

That would have shown you that your "syntax issue" was really a data issue, and what you had wasn't a number you could compare that way.
Any time you read in data from virtually any source it's usually worth verifying.
if [[ "$x" =~ [^[:digit:]] ]]; then some_error_handler "$x"; fi

